# How do I stop VS2008 from unnecessarily modifying my CSPROJ files?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, user-controls, project

For some reason, VS2008 just loves to arbitrarily add, then remove, then add, then remove (then repeat) my <user control> and <form> references to my CSPROJ project files.  It is incredibly irritating, and interrupts my SVN usage patterns.  Is there any cure for this minor but highly annoying bug?

Comment: I am not sure why it would do that, unless you explicitly include an UI element and then delete (or) add a reference to a library.

Comment: How is this .csproj file getting saved in the first place?  This is only automatic when you start building.  At which point it should not omit anything.

Comment: It prompts me to save before performing the offending operation.  Doesn't do it every time.  Seems to be related to the bug where VS2008 puts the wrong icon (class icon) on user controls.  Couldn't say for sure though.  Seems to be aggravated by doing UI work (didn't see that coming did ya? ha)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Visual Studio has this amazing feature built-it :-),

The thing is far worse when it does it with the form resource files, or localization files (.resx).

Our solution was including a client trigger in our SCM to order alphabetically the .resx files before commit. In this way we can easily merge the .csproj files and the .resx files, but I guess that it will not be your favorite solution.